# Error Exception: Trying to get property of non-object - laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito obtener los campos **ID** y **Name** de mi tabla pivote, he probado con esto

```
public function Display(){

$langservice = new langService(); 

$musgroups=$langservice->getMusgroup(session()->get('lang_id'));

    foreach($musgroups as $musgroup1){
        foreach($musgroup1 as $musgroup){
            echo 'name:'+$musgroup->name;
        }
    }
```

Pero aparece este error:

> "Trying to get property of non-object".

He probado a hacer `print_r($musgroups);` pero eso saca toda la tabla en bucle 12 veces.

Comment: Intuyo que tu problema está aquí `session()->get('lang_id' ` Ese session() no te debe estar devolviendo un objeto.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra `dump($musgroups)`?

Comment: @JDev lo que planteas es incorrecto, el uso planteado por el OP para obtener un valor de la sesión es correcto según la sintaxis de Laravel.

Comment: @Shaz vale si que no habia visto `$musgroup->name` y el unico sitio que le podia dar ese error era el otro.